# angular Error: safe is undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

I get the 'safe is undefined' error interacting with html, after it has been inserted dynamically into a page via an AJAX call. E.g. When an option is chosen on a select within this html this error is thrown, and select resets to default value. I'm guessing this has something to do with the dynamically inserted content not being added correctly to the scope, even though i am performing the compile operation

Initializing questionForm on $scope in the controller:

```
$scope.questionForm = {};
```

The compile operation being performed in the success block of the AJAX call:

```
var requestQuestions = response.trim(); 
var template = angular.element('<ng-form name="questionForm">'+requestQuestions+'</ng-form>');
var linkFn = $compile(template);
var element = linkFn($scope);
$(".form-horizontal").append(element);
```

The dynamically inserted html(after compile has been run):

```
<ng-form name="questionForm" class="ng-scope ng-dirty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required">
    <div ng-class="{'alert alert-danger': questionForm['question_18'].$invalid &amp;&amp; data.attempted}" class="form-group question alert alert-danger">
    <label class="col-sm-3">
        1. What sort of role is this
    </label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
         <div class="question_box">
           <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-11"><select required="required" ng-model="data.application.questions[18]" data-placement="left" data-toggle="tooltip" class="form-control dropdown-question ng-dirty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" name="question_18"><option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Please select an option</option><option class="question-item" data-desc="" value="16">Full Time</option><option class="question-item" data-desc="" value="17">Part Time</option><option class="question-item" data-desc="" value="18">Contract</option></select></div><div class="col-md-1 e-padding-5">
                        <span id="dropdown-tooltip" title="" data-placement="right" data-toggle="tooltip" class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign hide">
                        </span>
              </div>
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
<span ng-show="questionForm['question_18'].$error.required &amp;&amp; data.attempted" class="help-block">Required</span>
</div>
    <div ng-class="{'alert alert-danger': questionForm['question_19'].$invalid &amp;&amp; data.attempted}" class="form-group question">
    <label class="col-sm-3">
        2. Why is this role required to be filled?
    </label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
     <div class="question_box"><textarea ng-model="data.application.questions[19]" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid" name="question_19"></textarea></div>
    </div>
<span ng-show="questionForm['question_19'].$error.required &amp;&amp; data.attempted" class="help-block ng-hide">Required</span>
</div>
```

The strange thing is validation on these form elements actually works, will throw an error if the field is required and not filled in. example validation code:

```
<div ng-class="{'alert alert-danger': questionForm['question_19'].$invalid &amp;&amp; data.attempted}" class="form-group question">
```

Any help would be appreciated. version of angular is 1.2.16

Comment: Don't need to use `&amp;` in expressions. Can use `&&`. Where is that error being triggered? never seen that one before

Comment: Hi @charlietfl must've changed it to &amp; when i pasted into the editor, was && in the code itself.        assign: function(self, value, locals) {
        var key = indexFn(self, locals);
        // prevent overwriting of Function.constructor which would break ensureSafeObject check
        var safe = ensureSafeObject(obj(self, locals), parser.text);
        return safe[key] = value;'`line 10537 of angular.js

Comment: ahhh that would make sense

Answer (score 0):

1. Modifying the form validation in the ngclass sections to reference the sub form elements correctly e.g. :

   ng-class="{'alert alert-danger': questionForm.question_18.$invalid && data.attempted}"

2 Adding a watch in a directive which checked for the presence of a new child node within the div with the directive, if new length of child nodes was greater than previous length, compile html, updating the model

```
app.directive("requestQuestions",function($compile,$timeout){
return {
    //restrict:"E",
    // terminal:true,
    priority:1000,
    link:function(scope,element,attrs){
        scope.$watch(function () { return element[0].childNodes.length; },
            function(newVal,oldVal) {
                if(newVal !== oldVal) {
                    // if the new value is greater than one , need to remove the existing node
                    if(newVal > 1)element[0].removeChild(element[0].childNodes[0]);
                    $compile(element)(scope);
                }
            });
    }
};
```

});